# How would I highlight invalid input fields onChange?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I wanted to know how I would highlight invalid input fields onChange? Currently my form only checks to see whether an input field meets minimal requirements such as length, and that is fine, but I would like to have the invalid field in question highlighted with a border. If the field is then validated, onChange, it should go back to its normal state.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('form #response2').hide();
        $('.button2').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var valid = '';
            var required = ' is required';
            var first = $('form #first').val();
            var last = $('form #last').val();
            var email = $('form #email').val();
            var tempt = $('form #tempt').val();
            var tempt2 = $('form #tempt2').val();

            if (first = '' || first.length <= 1) {
                valid += '<p>Your first name' + required + '</p>';
            }

            if (last = '' || last.length <= 1) {
                valid += '<p>Your last name' + required + '</p>';
            }

            if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
                valid += '<p>Your e-mail address' + required + '</p>';
            }

            if (tempt != 'http://') {
                valid += '<p>We can\'t allow spam bots.</p>';
            }

            if (tempt2 != '') {
                valid += '<p>A human user' + required + '</p>';
            }

            if (valid != '') {
                $('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('error2')
                    .html('' +valid).fadeIn('fast');
            }

            else {
                $('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('processing2').html('<p style="top:0px; left:0px; text-align:center; line-height:1.5em;">Please wait while we process your information...</p>').fadeIn('fast');

                var formData = $('form').serialize();
                submitForm(formData);
            }

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you can use.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  if(value=='' || value.length<=1) {
    $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
  }
  else {
   $(this).css('border','none');
  }
 });
});
```

This code will highlight all input text fields on the form when you it is empty or with only one character. This code triggers with the keyboard key up event means when you press and release the key, key up event will be fired and this code will be executed. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If I follow you correctly, all you need:

```
$('#last, #email, #tempt, #tempt2').change(function () {
    // Put validation logic here using $(this)
});
```

One thing I recommend is to wrap up validation logic into a function you can call from both the `change` and `click` callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure you catch all the changes, you want to capture the keyup, bind, cut, copy, and paste events as follow.

```
$('.your-input1, .your-input2, ...').on("keyup bind cut copy paste", function()
    {
       ...your code...
    });
```

The 'change' event does not work the same way across all browsers from my experience. And somehow it won't always get called when something changes.